# Python not showing existing venv in interpreter select

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-venv

I have a shared flask web project I am working on with 2 other developers, one of the developers initialized the venv on his pc, uploaded his project structure to github from where I cloned his repo.

Now I when I start vscode and open the project folder, python does not auto detect the venv and asks if it should set is as the interpreter, the only option I have is the default system wide python install, and not the venv python interpreter.

I tried adding it to the list by using the command `python:select interpreter` and then finding the `python.exe` inside the venv/scripts folder, but this does not work and vscode still asks for a interpreter.

I also tried manually adding it inside of my workspace `settings.json` file like so

`"python.pythonPath": "C:\\laragon\\www\\Proftaak\\venv\\Scripts\\python.exe"/`

But vscode also gives an error on this saying the interpreter is not valid.

How would I fix this?

Comment: What are the version of python in venv and in system?

Comment: Do you start the venv before selecting the python interpreter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not expected to work as virtual environments are not designed or meant to be movable. They are meant to be created on each machine you need a virtual environment on. As such, I suspect that the virtual environment does not work outside of VS Code which could prevent it from selecting it as a possible working environment.

Comment: Managed to fix it by adding the .venv to a gitignore file, and have each of us start a new virtual enviorment and installing the requirements from a text file with pip install